# vb6 to vb.net listview FindItemWithText zero error

Tags: vb.net, listview, vb6

I am trying to use some VB6 code for a listview in my .net application. However, once it converted it to vb.net code i can not seem to get pass this:

```
Dim ListObj As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
ListObj = LV1.FindItemWithText(Name_Renamed, True, 0)
```

It keeps telling me

> InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'startIndex'. Parameter
>   name: startIndex

I've tried to input a **1** instead of a **0** but i still get the same error message as above. Any help would be great!

David

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this changes to your code

```
Dim ListObj As System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem 
if LV1.Items.Count > 0 then
    ListObj = LV1.FindItemWithText(Name_Renamed, True, 0)
end if
```

The overload of the method FindItemWithText taking the startindex parameter, throw the InvalidArgument exception when the items count is zero.